# Are there more cryptocurrencies based on the cryptonote protocol? If so what are the main differences?

Tags: cryptonote, ring-signatures, implementation

I read a bit about the history of Monero and how it forked away from bytecoin/bitmonero in 2014. I also remember that there was another currency using the cryptonote protocol called "Boolberry" at that time. Right now cryptonote appears to be a Monero exclusive, though I know that's most likely not correct.

So what's the status of other dead/alive cryptonote implementations? Are there other actively developed currencies based on it? If so what's their name, purpose, main differences... ?

Comment: There are many coins with different emission curves, and features. You may want to ask a more specific question about the coin(s) you are most curious about.

Comment: tbh my main goal was to get an overview about the different cryptonote implementations as this stackexchange will become the goto place for everything cryptonote related. more specific questions will most likely evolve from there. but I admit that the scope of my question is indeed broad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many other CryptoNote coins but their communities, usage, trading volumes and hashrate are much smaller than Monero. Here is a chronicalogical graphic of many of the coins and from where they were forked:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote#/media/File:Forks-tree-fixed.png

You mentioned Boolberry, which like Aeon was an innovator in the area of pruning. Boolberry was popular early because (in addition to pruning) it was the first CryptoNote coin with a working (but very basic) GUI. Its developer has been inactive for some time. Aeon has a visible lead developer (smooth) that is also a Monero core developer, so Aeon has received far more attention than Boolberry recently.

Many CryptoNote coins appear to have been created by the same parties:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0

Measured by Bitcointalk activity, I would estimate the most active CryptoNote communities are currently:

1. Monero (XMR) largest community (RingCT, LMDB, OpenAlias, tail emission, etc)
2. Aeon (AEON) (pruning, focus on low memory footprint)
3. Boolberry (BBR) (pruning)
4. DigitalNote (XDN) (PoA development following multiple name changes)
5. Bitcedi (BXC) (XDN fork with slower emission)
6. Bytecoin (BCN) (First CryptoNote, compelling evidence of fake creation date)
7. Dashcoin (DSH) (automated BCN fork without huge "premine")
8. Pebblecoin (XPB) (PoS)

All have operational blockchains and varying level of developer activity or complete absence of activity.

Comment: For the record: Aeon and XDN also have a tail emission.

Comment: @user36303 You are right about XDN but AEON tail emission has not yet been implemented https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4t4e8g/please_add_raeon_as_a_related_sub_almost_every/d5f4zhh

Comment: Oh, you're right :)